# How to run a MYSQL script using a password from a command line?

Tags: mysql, passwords

When I try to connect to the remote MYSQL database through the command line this works fine despite the warning:

```
/sdzf => mysql -h db3  -u auser -ppassword DB_6 -A
Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
```

However, running a script does not work

```
/sdzf => mysql -h db3  -u auser -ppassword DB_6 -A< findrec.sql
Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
ERROR 1045 (28000) at line 1: Access denied for user 'auser'@'50.206.86.74'     
(using password: YES)
```

Comment: You forgot the space between -p and password.

Comment: If you login as auser and try to execute the script manually, does it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite my login statement included the database name I still needed to point to the database first in my SQL script when running in the batch mode:

USE DB_6;

If I login first using the same script "mysql -h db3  -u auser -ppassword DB_6 -A" then I do not need to point to the database in my SQL.